# Performance difference of neighbor selection for Traveling Salesman using Simulated Annealing

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman

Recently I tried a few different neighbor selection algorithms for solving the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) using [Simulated Annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing):

1. Swap two random cities (e.g. `abcdefg -> abfdecg`)
2. Cut route into two and swap the two sub-routes (e.g. `ab|cdefg -> cdefgab`)
3. Swap two random adjacent cities (e.g. `abcdefg -> abdcefg`)
4. Swap two random sub-routes (e.g. `a|bc|d|ef|g -> aefdbcg`)
5. Reverse a random sub-route (e.g. `ab|cdef|g -> abfedcg`)

It turns out there is a huge difference in asymptotic performance.  #5 turned out to be the best and #2 turned out to not work at all.

Why such a huge difference with #2 and #5? Both algorithms change two edges at a time. In the above examples, #2 changes breaks `bc` and attaches `ga`. #5 replaces `bc` with `bf` and replaces `fg` with `cg`. Why does #2 not work at all while #5 is the best of the 5?

Comment: 1: How did you check the performances? Which kind of instances you are generating (e.g. real-world vs.random) 2: The no free lunch theorem guarantees, that all these algs are equally performant if used on "all possible instances" -> this explains why 1 is so important. 3. As an implication of 2: i think, that you may find out that some other alg is better than #5, if you play with your Simulated Annealing parameters (cooling rate). Not that i think #5 is bad, but well, everything is so dependent on instances/params. 4. Maybe check the TSP-literature (there is a lot).

Comment: Another remark: let's try to think about these algorithms in terms of exploitation / exploration: #2 seems to be a very "big" local operator (huge neighborhood) which diversifies a lot. #5 is much "bigger" that e.g. #1, but maybe more intensifying the search than #2. If this is the case, again, it's highly dependent on your Meta-Heuristic and parameters + instance types, which will work better!

Comment: I am generating random instances, and I have been running these algorithms for millions of trials. The cost plateaus are reached for all the trials (by plateau I mean the point where the cost flattens and/or decreases extremely slowly). There seem to be different plateaus for different algorithms but #2 just never makes any headway at all.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't understand your problem, but as far as I know, the TSP requires that all cities are visited in a closed loop, so at which city you start does not change the overall distance. Your strategy #2 appears to be a *cyclic permutation*, i.e. same loop but different starting point, so no wonder it does not improve anything!

Strategy #5 works well since it will potentially remove two crossing edges:

```
a--b f--e           a--b--f--e
|   X   |    -->    |        |
\--g c--d           \--g--c--d
```

Note that #5 only modifies 2 edges. Your strategy #4 modifies 4 edges at the same time, so the probability that this improves the route might be very low. Furthermore, strategy #1 is a special case of #4, and #3 a special case of #5.